# how to get all values from childsnapshots into a variable before passing on the variable to a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, callback, promise, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all the value of the childsnapshot into a variable and pass the values to a function which is supposed to create a graph with the values,
I am not able to collect all the values and pass , I have tried callbacks but couldn't implement it correctly

here is the code snippet::

```
dbref
        .once("value")
            .then
                (
                    function(snapshot)
                        {
                        snapshot.forEach
                            (
                            function(childsnapshot)
                            {
                             var data = childsnapshot.val();

                             var Nameval=data.Name;

                             if(Nameval==namekey)
                             {
                             console.log("Success");

                             Ikey=childsnapshot.key();

var dxRef=new Firebase("https://apraisalstaging.firebaseio.com/EmployeeDB/EApraise/"+Ikey); 

                          dxRef
                            .once("value")
                                .then
                                (
                                    function(snapshot)
                                        {

                                            snapshot.forEach
                                            (

                                                function(childsnapshot)
                                                {

                                                    var data=childsnapshot.val();
                                                    var Rtdate=data.Dateval;
                                                    console.log(Rtdate);


                                                }
```

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen please take a look

Answer (score 0):

There's more people here then just Frank... sometimes. I've adjusted your code a little to help me figure out your issue and I highly suggest you look into how promises work. Without much to go on here is what I was able to come up with:

```
dbref
    .once("value")
    .then(function (snapshot) {
        var promises = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function (childsnapshot) {
            var data = childsnapshot.val();
            var Nameval = data.Name;

            if (Nameval == namekey) {
                console.log("Success");

                Ikey = childsnapshot.key();

                var dxRef = new Firebase("https://apraisalstaging.firebaseio.com/EmployeeDB/EApraise/" + Ikey);

                promises.push(dxRef
                    .once("value")
                    .then(function (snapshot) {
                        var returnData = [];
                        snapshot.forEach(function (childsnapshot) {
                            var data = childsnapshot.val();
                            var Rtdate = data.Dateval;
                            console.log(Rtdate);
                            returnData.push(Rtdate);
                        });
                        return returnData;
                    }));
            }
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
```

This will create an array of promises that will resolve once all of the sub requests have resolved and then you can see the console.log(result) at the bottom. That's where you would call your function.

Comment: Ran your code got the following error                                        Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $q is not defined at testcallback.html:65
(anonymous) @ testcallback.html:65
testcallback.html:58 10/2/2017
testcallback.html:59 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.push is not a function

Comment: Can you use plain javascript

Comment: Hey, I updated to use vanially js and also fixed a small bug.